what is the powder on my fish tank?
I have a white power like substance on the upper 1/8th of my fish tank and filters.
I wash and wipe it, but it never really goes away.
What is it and how do I get rid of it?
Full disclosure - I am not very religious on water changes.


related:https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26641/what-could-i-use-to-clean-limescale-off-of-tank-glass it answers your question about what it is and how to remove it.

thanks you for the feedback
